# Combining common and specific variables

Tags: ansible

In `group_vars` I want to have common variables and definitions, and for every specific environment I'd like to have just specific variables that will kind of point to common variables. There should be logic in specific environment variables, e.g. if I set to `manual` or `auto`, it should inherit the specific part in common variables. Let's say I have in common vars `group_vars/all`:

```yaml
software:
  enabled: true
  manual:
    enabled: true #default
    packages: 
       - package1
       - package2
  auto:
    enabled: false #default
    gpg_key: key_path
    repo: repo_name
    packages: 
       - package1
       - package2
```

Now, in specific variables (`group_vars/production`), I want to define just that for this environment, packages will be installed `auto`, so I should enable auto:

```yaml
software:
  enabled: true
  auto: 
    enabled: true
  manual: 
    enabled: false
```

Now when I run a task, e.g. to add a GPG key

```yaml
- name: Add GPG apt Key
  apt_key:
    url: "{{ software.auto.gpg_key }}"
    state: present
  when: software.enabled and software.auto.enabled
  register: install_automatic_custom_repo_gpg_key_output
```

`include_vars` and `vars_files` doesn't work, playbook/task is not loading common variables, just specific ones.

Any idea how to handle this? I have lots of environments and definitions, and I want to avoid having them always specified in every single environment, that's why I wanted to have list of all packages and configurations in a single file, and just define in specific vars what installation method to use (manual or auto).
I am open to any other suggestions, maybe separating vars like this isn't a good approach at all.

**EDIT**

all:

```
software:
  prerequisites:
    enabled: true
    install:
      automatic:
        enabled: true
        custom_repo:
          enabled: false
          gpg_key_url:
          source_string:
        packages:
          - python3-pip
          - python3-docker
        ansible_galaxy_collections:
          - kubernetes.core
          - cloud.common
          - community.kubernetes
        pip_install:
          - ansible
          - kubernetes
          - openshift
      manual:
        enabled: false
        version: 
        binary_relative_path:
        download:
          enabled: true  
          url: 
        dependencies:
          enabled: true
          list:
            - python3-wheel_0.37.1-2ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb
            - python3-websocket_1.2.3-1_all.deb
        packages:
          - python3-docker_5.0.3-1_all.deb
          - python3-pip_22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb
        pip_install:
          - kubernetes
          - openshift
        ansible_galaxy_collections:
  docker:
    enabled: true
    install:
      automatic:
        enabled: true
        custom_repo:
          enabled: true
          gpg_key_url: "https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg"
          source_string: "deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
        packages:
          - docker-ce
          - docker-ce-cli
          - containerd.io
      manual:
        enabled: false
        version: 
        binary_relative_path:
        download:
          enabled: true  
          url: 
        dependencies:
          enabled: true
          list:
            - containerd.io_1.6.20-1_amd64.deb
        packages:
          - docker-ce-cli_23.0.2-1_ubuntu.20.04_focal_amd64.deb
          - docker-ce_23.0.2-1_ubuntu.20.04_focal_amd64.deb
    configure:
      config_dir: "/etc/docker"
      config_file: "/etc/docker/daemon.json"
      user: "ubuntu"
      group: "ubuntu"
...
```

specific vars:

```
software:
  prerequisites:
    enabled: true
    install:
      automatic:
        enabled: true
      manual:
        enabled: false
  docker:
    enabled: true
    install:
      automatic:
        enabled: true
      manual:
        enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour as you describe it

> playbook/task is not loading common vars, just specific ones.

**is** actually happening correctly, but **because** you stored your variable under a dictionary, the following happens:

> **DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR**
>
> Description: This setting controls how duplicate definitions of
> dictionary variables (aka hash, map, associative array) are handled in
> Ansible.
>
> Default choices: **replace**: Any variable that is defined more than
> once is overwritten using the order from variable precedence rules
> (highest wins).

<sup>Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour</sup>

But, please don't rush in changing this behaviour, as warned extensively in the same documentation page:

> This does not affect variables whose values are scalars (integers, strings) or arrays. **WARNING**, changing this setting is not recommended as this is fragile and makes your content (plays, roles, collections) non portable, leading to continual confusion and misuse. Don’t change this setting unless you think you have an absolute need for it. We recommend avoiding reusing variable names and relying on the `combine` filter and `vars` and `varnames` lookups to create merged versions of the individual variables. In our experience this is rarely really needed and a sign that too much complexity has been introduced into the data structures and plays. For some uses you can also look into custom vars_plugins to merge on input, even substituting the default `host_group_vars` that is in charge of parsing the `host_vars/` and `group_vars/` directories. Most users of this setting are only interested in inventory scope, but the setting itself affects all sources and makes debugging even harder. All playbooks and roles in the official examples repos assume the default for this setting. Changing the setting to `merge` applies across variable sources, but many sources will internally still overwrite the variables. For example `include_vars` will dedupe variables internally before updating Ansible, with ‘last defined’ overwriting previous definitions in same file. The Ansible project recommends **you avoid `merge` for new projects**. It is the intention of the Ansible developers to eventually deprecate and remove this setting, but it is being kept as some users do heavily rely on it. New projects should **avoid ‘merge’**.

---

So, from there, you have the solution to use `combine`, as explained in the documentation:

*group_vars/all:*

```yaml
default_software:
  enabled: true
  manual:
    enabled: true #default
    packages: 
       - package1
       - package2
  auto:
    enabled: false #default
    gpg_key: key_path
    repo: repo_name
    packages: 
       - package1
       - package2
```

*group_vars/production:*

```yaml
software_specific:
  enabled: true
  auto: 
    enabled: true
  manual: 
    enabled: false
```

Then, either as a first task of your playbook or even, in `pre_tasks`:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    software: >-
      {{ 
        software 
          | combine(software_specific | default({}), recursive=True) 
      }}
```

---

Or, you have the solution to make those variable, that needs to be overridden, scalars — boolean for this case:

In *group_vars/all*:

```yaml
software_enabled: true
software_manual_enabled: true
software_auto_enabled: false

software:
  enabled: "{{ software_enabled }}"
  manual:
    enabled: "{{ software_manual_enabled }}"
    packages: 
       - package1
       - package2
  auto:
    enabled: "{{ software_auto_enabled }}"
    gpg_key: key_path
    repo: repo_name
    packages: 
       - package1
       - package2
```

In *group_vars/production:*

```yaml
software_enabled: true
software_manual_enabled: false
software_auto_enabled: true
```

---

Also, in your explanation, I'll definitely see a use case where you could *[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)* your code even further; doing:

```yaml
software_manual_enabled: true

# The dictionary  have been reduced to only showcase the improved part
software:
  manual:
    enabled: "{{ software_manual_enabled }}"
  auto:
    enabled: "{{ not software_manual_enabled }}"
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, please see the edit to see how exactly I defined all vars, I don't think it is a good idea..

Comment: What is not a good idea? How is the first solution, using `combine` not answering your question, regardless of the structure or complexity of data?

Comment: it is working, but just wondering should i maybe reorganize everything with different logic..

Comment: Should you want to rewrite just with higher precedence, then yes, use scalars, their overriding would work flawlessly, as explained in the second solution provided here.